# reCAPTCHA Enterprise Service Status

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

We need to know if the reCAPTCHA service is down since we don't want to lose contact form submissions if reCAPTCHA is nor working. Is there an API or workaround to check the service status?

Answer (score 0):

Checking on our [Status page](https://status.cloud.google.com/), there is no problem or issue with recaptcha.
On the Webpage(bottom right) you should have Google Captcha icon

[image]

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898959/how-to-know-if-recaptcha-v3-works-or-not) as reference for checking about the status of your recaptcha.